# Heat Equation Two Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, heat-equation

I'm currently working on solving the Heat Equation in a one dimensional rod of length $L$. However, instead of the 'usual' singular condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$ for all $0\leq x\leq L$, I am given

$u(x,0)=f(x)$ for $0\leq x \leq L/2$.

$u(x,0)=g(x)$ for $L/2 \leq x \leq L$.

I can find the solutions individually for each of these conditions, but what do I do with these two solutions to solve the PDE? Or am I supposed to have two separate solutions, one for each half of the rod?

My gut feeling is telling me to sum the two, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Is $f({L\over 2}) = g({L \over 2})$?

Comment: Not for this one. However, I can observe that $f(x)+g(x)$ is a constant, if that helps.

Comment: This is still one function.  Your one function equals f(x) on the left side and equals g(x) on the right side.  Do what you would normally do.

Comment: You just need to deal with the discontinuity and any related convergence issues (presumably you are using Fourier series here?). Imagine the initial condition as two half-length rods being brought together.

Comment: Indeed I am using Fourier Series, but the functions are continuous everywhere, as they are both linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have a single function specifying the heat distribution, it just happens to be given by a function defined piecewise:

$$u_0(x) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
    f(x), & 0 \leq x \leq \tfrac{L}{2} \\
    g(x), & \tfrac{L}{2} \leq x \leq L
\end{array}
\right. .$$

Assuming you're using Fourier series to solve the evolution problem, use that

$$\int_0^L h(x) u_0(x) \,dx = \int_0^{\frac{L}{2}} h(x)  f(x) \,dx + \int_{\frac{L}{2}}^L h(x) g(x).$$